# Inserting data into Object type table from another existing table..Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, object-type

I am trying to insert data into an object type table from another existing table in a stored procedure.
I created the "object" type and it's type "table" as below example.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EXAMPLE AS OBJECT
(
ALL THE COLUMNS,
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EXAMPLE_TABLE AS TABLE OF EXAMPLE;
```

trying to use this type table to get the data inserted from another table.

```
---
BEGIN
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TABLE (ALL THE COLUMS FROM EXAMPLE) 
VALUES (SELECT * FROM EMP_TABLE);
```

is this possible? let me know, or should I use the "CURSOR" to insert one by one..
please let me know how to achieve this,in the form of syntax

--thank you in advance

Comment: The definition of `emp_table` would be helpful, as would including the actual fields/columns you're using instead of 'all the columns'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example table is a type so you can't insert anything into it, first you would need to define a variable that would be an instance of your example_table. Then you can use a bulk collect to actually populate your table.

```
declare
  example_tab_inst EXAMPLE_TABLE;
begin
  select 
   EXAMPLE(e.col1,e.col2,e.col3) 
  bulk collect into example_tab_inst 
  from emp_table e;
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: ohh cool... but how can I put this whole object type in a stored procedure?? I tried creating an object type inside a stored procedure, but donot know if its the correct format... could you please put these steps in a stored procedure and let me know a proper format??. thank you..

Comment: You can't define an object inside a stored procedure, you can only use it there. Your create type statement will create the object then you can use the object inside your stored procedure as I did above. Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm) for more information.